# How does Cohen's theorem of transfinite induction relate to the the reagular (or more modern) one?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, transfinite-induction

My understanding of transfinite induction comes from Weaver where he says:

---

Theorem: Suppose that for every ordinal $\alpha$

$(\forall\beta<\alpha)\phi(\beta)\rightarrow\phi(\alpha)$

holds. Then $(\forall\alpha)\phi(\alpha)$ holds.

---

I understand this statement - it is a pretty clear extension of "regular" induction - essentially that if knowing $\phi$ is true for all smaller ordinals tell you that $\phi$ is true for the "next" ordinal then $\phi$ is true for all ordinals.

However, Cohen formulation is very different and I'm having trouble following it. He says (note: Cohen also uses $\phi$ in his formulation, but I think it means something different, so I replaced it with $\psi$ to try to avoid confusion):

---

Definition: let $A_n(x,y,t_1,...t_k)$ run through all formulas in ZF with at least two free variables

Theorem: Let $t_i$ be given and assume $\forall x \exists!yA_n(x,y,t_1,...,t_k)$ so that $A$ defines a function $y=\psi(x)$. For every ordinal $\alpha$ and set $z$ there is a unique function $f$ defined on $\{\beta|\beta\leq\alpha\}$ (this is actually the set $\alpha+1$), such that $f(0)=z$ and for all $\beta\leq\alpha$, $f(\beta)=\psi(h)$ where $h$ is $f$ restricted to $\beta$.

---

I'm not able to relate these two theorems. I *think* Weaver's $\phi$ is Cohen's $A_n$ but I'm not sure. Here are some thoughts I've tried:

**Thought 1:** I've tried to start at $\alpha=0$. Since $0=\emptyset$, then $h$ being $f$ restricted to $0$ is empty i.e. $h=\emptyset$. That means that:

$f(0)=z=\psi(\emptyset)$

But here, I'm already stuck. This is supposed to hold for *every* $z$ but it can't be true because $\psi(\emptyset)$ is unique.

**Thought 2:** But, okay, let's say that $f(0)=z$ and the statement $f(\beta)=\psi(h)$ only holds for ordinals greater than $0$. So, then, $f(1)=\phi(h)$ where $h$ is the function mapping $0$ to $z$ (I suppose $h=\{\{0, \{0,h\}\}\}$). So now we know what $f(1)$ is. And we can keep going to $f(2), f(3), ...$ and then $f(\omega)$, etc.... So we've got some function $f$ defined and being "built up" from how $\psi$ "tells us" what to do next (given that we started from $z$). But I still don't see how to relate this back to Weaver's formulation and a way of proving some statement is true for all ordinals.

Any help relating the two, or just understanding what Cohen's formulation is saying, is appreciated.

---

P.S. before anyone asks, I'm just reading Cohen for fun.

Answer (score 2):

I checked with some friends and got an answer to this myself.

**Thought 1:** since $f(0) = z$, the statement of the theorem really should be "for all $\beta$ such that $0<\beta\leq\alpha$, $f(\beta)=\psi(h)$".

**Thought 2:** Cohen's version is really more "Transfinite Recursion" than it is "Transfinite Induction." In other words, given a statement $A_n$ and a set $z$ you can prove that there is a function $f$ on the ordinals where $f(\beta)$ only depends on how $f$ works on ordinals less than $\beta$.

The two versions (what I'm calling Weaver's and Cohen's) are equally powerful since you can get each from the other.